# android stopping another application

Tags: android

I have been trying to do some research for this but I did not find the one I was looking for.

So, what I would like my application to do, is simply stop another application.

If I would use `.bat` and `.exe` examples like I do with my computer, I would like stop `.bat` tho stop `notepad.exe`.

It do not care will it stay as a background app or no.

Comment: You need to understand that Android is not Windows. The two operating systems work in completely different ways and things that might work in Windows may not even be possible in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only kill your own applications, as each app runs sandboxed as a separate Linux user.
If this is no problem for your use case, [killBackgroundProcesses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29) should do what you're looking for. An additional requirement for this is the `KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission.